# CSS image scrolling animation stopping too soon

Tags: html, css, wordpress, animation

I have the following code in a HTML Block on a Wordpress website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Durchlaufendes Band aus Bildern mit CSS</title>

  <style>
    #bildband-container {
      overflow: hidden; 
      width: 100%;
    }

    
    #bildband {
      display: flex;
      animation: scroll 10s linear infinite; 
    }

    @keyframes scroll {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }

    
    img {
      width: auto; 
      height: 300px; 
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="bildband-container">
    <div id="bildband">
      <img src="url1" alt="">
      <img src="url2" alt="">
      <img src="url3" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to scroll sideways through some images/logos in an infinite band.
The URLs are correct and it seems to work but stops after ~1.5 images and goes back to the start.
The images are all different sizes so that might be a problem since it worked when they were all set to the same width with auto height (width: 100px, height: auto).
Also if I adjust the height to something higher it stops even sooner. I honestly dont know what I am missing here.

I tried removing `object-fit: cover;` and using different scroll speeds and heights of the images. Also I triple checked the URLs were not the problem and even used the same image 3 times. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can you upload your images somewhere and adjust the code in your question so we could reproduce your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I could try to make some blank images of the same size later and upload them though.

Comment: I only care about the size of the images and the testability of the code. Please don't make them blank. Instead make some images of the same size that contains something so we can see whether they are being scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 10s with 200ms(or something less than 10s) to fast the animation. This decreases the duration of the whole animation.

```
#bildband {
  display: flex;
  animation: scroll 10s linear infinite; 
}
```

This will automatically increase the speed!
If the animation stop then add an 50% keyframe like this:

```
@keyframes youranimation{
    0%{
         transform:translateX(0%);
    }
    50%{
         transform:translateX(-100%); 
    }
    100%{
        transform:translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not about the speed. No matter the speed the animation still stops after 1.5 images

Comment: @O1ez If you want to make a carousel then add some buttons translate on the X axis. Increase the translation of X axis by 100px on every forward button click.

Answer (score 0):

Just add more keyframes:

```css
@keyframes scroll {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      25% {
        transform: translateX(25%);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translateX(50%);
      }
      75% {
        transform: translateX(75%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Still does the same thing. But I noticed it is scrolling in the wrong direction. I have to use -25% etc to scroll correctly.

Comment: @O1ez Do you want to make a carousel?

Comment: Yes, that's basically the effect I am trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting a smooth continuous flow is to have two copies of the images and move the container just 50% of its width before starting again.

And make the container have at least twice the width of its container (the snippet uses a min-width of 200vw in this example).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Durchlaufendes Band aus Bildern mit CSS</title>

  <style>
    #bildband-container {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 200vw;
    }
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #bildband {
      display: flex;
      width: fit-content;
      min-width: 200vw;
      justify-content: space-around;
      animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes scroll {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
    }
    
    img {
      width: auto;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="bildband-container">
    <div id="bildband">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/300" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/300" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/300" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```